# Importing specific rows of a text file while keeping header

Tags: r, text, import

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
"Saved at:19 January 2015, 1:01 PM"
"Course"    "Time"  
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 7:28 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 7:27 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 7:26 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 7:25 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 7:02 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 7:02 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 6:57 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 6:57 PM"
The DI Module Exam contains 16 mul..."
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 6:57 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 6:57 PM"
```

where in using `read.delim` I specified `skip=1` and then used the second line as header. Some times, there are lines like the 11th line (could be anything else) that should be skipped during the import process. I want to if there's a way, specially in R base, to

1. skip the first line,
2. have the second line as header and
3. skip lines that don't start with `"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"`.

FYI, this is the code I use to import text file:

```
read.delim("path to the file",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,strip.white=TRUE,na.strings=c("NA",""),skip=1)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389196/importing-text-data-into-r-and-removing-extraneous-headers-and-other-unwanted-te?rq=1

Comment: @bsg Thanks for the link. That looks to be able to do the job but I have large files (e.g. up 40,000 lines) that those `for` loops may slow down the process. Is there other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to conditionally exclude lines with `read.table`, but reading in with readLines and creating an inclusion vector with grep or grepl seems effective:

```
Lines <- readLines(textConnection('"Saved at:19 January 2015, 1:01 PM"
"Course"    "Time"  
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 7:28 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 7:27 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 7:26 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 7:25 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 7:02 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 7:02 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 6:57 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 6:57 PM"
The DI Module Exam contains 16 mul..."
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 6:57 PM"
"EDPY 301 (SEM J4 Wi14)"    "28 January 2014, 6:57 PM"'))

good <- grep("^\\\"EDPY", Lines)
inp <- read.table(text=Lines[good], col.names = c("Course","Time" ))
```

The pattern string needs to have three slashes after the start-of-line-marker, two to make a slash and the third to escape a double-quote.

Comment: This seems promising.Thanks. I have my text stored in `txt` files. How can I import a `txt` file using `readLines`?  It seems that it only reads in text and not text files.

Comment: Not so. You can just substitute `con="filepath/to/your/filename.txt"` for the textConnection call.